# Deleting a file in afterDelete() - CakePHP

Tags: php, file, cakephp, delete-file

I have an Upload model - contains images uploaded by the user.

Within the controller, I'm calling:

```
$this->Upload->delete($id);
```

Which works just fine to delete the record from the database, but I'd also like to delete the corresponding image file.

I've tried a lot of different things with different variables..etc, and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264424/model-callback-beforedelete) to a similar question, but - nothing seems to work - I can't even get it to delete with any of these attempts:

```
//at the bottom of my Upload model
function afterDelete() {
    //NONE OF THESE WORK - is this even being called?
    unlink('/img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    unlink('app/webroot/img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    unlink('/app/webroot/img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    unlink('img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    unlink(WWW_ROOT . '/img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');
    return true;
}
```

Obviously I'll want to change it to be a dynamic filename, but for now, I can't even get it to delete the file when hard-coding all the different possible paths I can think of.

Is there a way to test what's going on in this?  Like an echo or... anything?

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you hardcode paths instead of passing just the one you use as argument to the function?

Comment: your calling `$this->Upload->delete($id);` should you not be calling `$this->Upload->afterDelete($id);` & your missing an argument in the function `$id` this should trigger an error, do you have error reporting on

Comment: @Dave Do you have privileges to be able to delete from that directory?

Comment: @Damien - I hardcoded just to see if I could get it to work AT ALL

Comment: @Lawrence - I don't believe I should be calling afterDelete() - my assumption is that is triggered automatically when you call delete() - is that not the case?  I'm not missing an argument because I'm not calling afterDelete.  Maybe you're thinking this is normal PHP instead of CakePHP?

Comment: @martswite - I believe so - I'll triple check - my upload script is working fine to that folder

Comment: @martswife - yes - permissions are correct

Comment: Please, remove "image-processing" tag.

Comment: Kill the script inside the `afterDelete` method, eg. `die("inside after delete");`. You'll know if it works if the script exits and displays that string.

Comment: Did you already debug what the unlink() method returns? Do they all return false?

Comment: @Dave Your assumption is correct, `afterDelete()` gets triggered when you call `delete`.

Comment: What does your logfile tell you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

// new File(string $path, boolean $create = false, integer $mode = 493) 
// $mode  = 493 default

$file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg', false, 0777);
if($file->delete()) {
   echo 'image deleted.....';
}
```

[Detail about File Utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#file-api)

Answer (score 2):

I tried deleting a file in afterDelete() and didn't find any issues..It worked for me..

```
    function afterDelete() {
        if(unlink(WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/2.png")) {
            echo "Successful";
        }
        else echo "Unsuccessful";
}
```

I don't know what is the problem with your code...Maybe your problem is how to delete the same file after its record has been deleted. For that you can use the beforeDelete() function to store the image name in a certain variable and then use it in afterDelete().

Answer (score 1):

This is an `afterDelete` I use and that works perfectly on my project, try it and see:

```
public function afterDelete() {
    $file = new File($this->data['MyModel']['file_path']);
    $file->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't use debug or a normal echo print_r($val,1);. You could mail yourself the results of this code with the php mail() function:

```
$perms = fileperms('/the/path/the_file.ext');
```

It should be something like 0755.

You could also echo all of this and place a die('die!'); at the end of the function and look what happens. 
Either way, if you don't get a email or the executions stops, something is wrong.

By the way, this is probably the right path:  unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/rest_logo.jpg');

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to give you my solution. At the end you can see I use the `unlink()` function and I can assure you that it works.

I use a this function inside a Component with another set of ImageFunctions

```
function getImageAbsolutePath( $upload_id ){
    //To use the model in the Component
    $this->Upload = ClassRegistry::init('Upload');

    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Upload.id' => $upload_id
        )
    );

    $upload = $this->Upload->find( 'first', $options );

    if( isset( $upload['Upload'] ) && $upload['Upload']['id'] > 0 ){
        $imgPath = WWW_ROOT . "files" . DS . "uploads" . DS . $upload['Upload']['name'];
    }else{
        $imgPath = "";
    }

    return $imgPath;

}
```

In the controller

```
        $filePath = $uploadComponent->getImageAbsolutePath( $id );

        if( $filePath != '' && file_exists( $filePath ) ){
            if ($this->Upload->delete($id)) {
                unlink($filePath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm capable of deleting a file with unlink - the question is how to do it when triggered by "afterDelete()"

Comment: This is not a good approach because you'll have to make sue you *always* and explicitly unlink the file after deleting.